# MySQL - Stored Procedure or Simple Join to get values from one table into other Based on filter and max value

Tags: mysql, join, stored-procedures

I would like to know what's the better way to execute the following action in mysql:

If i have a table A with the following structure and dummy data:

```
+------------+-----+
|   Dates    | ID  |
+------------+-----+
| 01/01/2017 | 123 |
| 02/01/2017 | 123 |
| 03/01/2017 | 123 |
| 04/01/2017 | 123 |
| 06/01/2017 | 123 |
| 07/01/2017 | 123 |
| 01/01/2017 | 124 |
| 02/01/2017 | 124 |
| 03/01/2017 | 124 |
| 04/01/2017 | 124 |
| 06/01/2017 | 124 |
| 07/01/2017 | 124 |
+------------+-----+
```

and a table B with some info were i want to get Attribute data from:

```
+------------+-----+-----------+
|   Dates    | ID  | Attribute |
+------------+-----+-----------+
| 29/12/2016 | 123 | AA        |
| 30/12/2016 | 123 | AB        |
| 31/12/2016 | 123 | AC        |
| 01/01/2017 | 123 | AD        |
| 03/01/2017 | 123 | AF        |
| 04/01/2017 | 123 | AA        |
| 07/01/2017 | 123 | AF        |
| 10/01/2017 | 123 | AC        |
| 27/12/2016 | 124 | BA        |
| 28/12/2016 | 124 | BB        |
| 29/12/2016 | 124 | BC        |
| 30/12/2016 | 124 | BD        |
| 31/12/2016 | 124 | BE        |
| 02/01/2017 | 124 | BF        |
| 04/01/2017 | 124 | BA        |
| 06/01/2017 | 124 | AA        |
| 07/01/2017 | 124 | AC        |
| 11/01/2017 | 124 | BF        |
+------------+-----+-----------+
```

How would one join the 2 tables in order to get the Attribute info, according to the following conditions:

1. In many records, from table A, there won't be a matching date in table B so cant have a direct and simple join on ID and dates;
2. When there isn't a matching date d, in table B, for a given ID in table A, then I need to get the attribute from the immediately previous date (this previous date can be one day before or several days before date d).

The result table that I would like to obtain is something like this, in the table below:

```
+----------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+
| Dates (from table A) | ID ( from table A ) | Attribute ( from table B ) |
+----------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+
| 01/01/2017           |                 123 | AD                         |
| 02/01/2017           |                 123 | AD                         |
| 03/01/2017           |                 123 | AF                         |
| 04/01/2017           |                 123 | AA                         |
| 06/01/2017           |                 123 | AA                         |
| 07/01/2017           |                 123 | AF                         |
| 01/01/2017           |                 124 | BE                         |
| 02/01/2017           |                 124 | BF                         |
| 03/01/2017           |                 124 | BF                         |
| 04/01/2017           |                 124 | BA                         |
| 06/01/2017           |                 124 | AA                         |
| 07/01/2017           |                 124 | AC                         |
+----------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+
```

Please note, as an example:
For ID = 123 in day 02/01/2017, there isn't any record in table B, so I need to get Attribute from the day immediately before, which in this case is the attribute from day 01/01/2017 - Attribute = AD.

As you can see this is dummy data that resembles my real data, and my real data have several hundreds of registries in each table. So, I am also looking a solution that will perform well my database. I thought that perhaps we need a stored procedure that loops through each row from table A and get the results I expect, is this a good thought? At the same time, I wonder if this could be accomplished with a join operation...I'm really confused right now :)

I hope this explanation is clear enough, and I am truly sorry if something like this has been answered before. However, I've been digging into this a couple of days now, and I've done plenty of searches, but I didn't find an answer to a similar problem.
I appreciate your help, in advance.
Cheers.

EDIT: I changed the therms registry/registries for record/records.

Comment: What's a registry?

Comment: It would be useful to post up a fiddle.

Comment: @ P.Salmon a Registry, in a table, is a whole line. I'm sorry if this isn't the correct term to use in english, I am just translating it by the concept I know in my natural language :)

@Strawberry I would gladly post a fiddle, but I honestly don't understand how those work. If you could point me some sources, to quickly learn it and to quickly deploy a fiddle example i will gladly do it.

Thank you both, for taking the time to think about this question.

Comment: @P.Salmon i was thinking about the registry issue yesterday, i came to the conclusion that what i meant is Record. This therm is used in Power Query, and as a big power query user like I am i should have remebered this earlier. I'm sorry if i misslead you, or others, in some way using the term registry and not record.
Anyway, i edited my original post and changed the words, so people won't get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be with a correlated sub query, for example

```
drop table if exists tb;
drop table if exists ta;
create table ta(Dates date,    ID  int);
insert into ta values
(str_to_date('01/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),123), 
(str_to_date('02/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),123), 
(str_to_date('03/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),123), 
(str_to_date('04/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),123), 
(str_to_date('06/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),123), 
(str_to_date('07/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),123), 
(str_to_date('01/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),124), 
(str_to_date('02/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),124), 
(str_to_date('03/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),124), 
(str_to_date('04/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),124), 
(str_to_date('06/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),124), 
(str_to_date('07/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),124);

create table tb(   Dates  date,   ID int ,Attribute varchar(2));
insert into tb values
( str_to_date('29/12/2016','%d/%m/%Y'),123 , 'AA'),        
( str_to_date('30/12/2016','%d/%m/%Y'),123 , 'AB'),        
( str_to_date('31/12/2016','%d/%m/%Y'),123 , 'AC'),        
( str_to_date('01/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),123 , 'AD'),        
( str_to_date('03/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),123 , 'AF'),        
( str_to_date('04/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),123 , 'AA'),        
( str_to_date('07/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),123 , 'AF'),        
( str_to_date('10/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),123 , 'AC'),        
( str_to_date('27/12/2016','%d/%m/%Y'),124 , 'BA'),        
( str_to_date('28/12/2016','%d/%m/%Y'),124 , 'BB'),        
( str_to_date('29/12/2016','%d/%m/%Y'),124 , 'BC'),        
( str_to_date('30/12/2016','%d/%m/%Y'),124 , 'BD'),        
( str_to_date('31/12/2016','%d/%m/%Y'),124 , 'BE'),        
( str_to_date('02/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),124 , 'BF'),        
( str_to_date('04/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),124 , 'BA'),        
( str_to_date('06/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),124 , 'AA'),        
( str_to_date('07/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),124 , 'AC'),        
( str_to_date('11/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y'),124 , 'BF');


select ta.dates, ta.id,(select attribute from tb where tb.id = ta.id and tb.dates <= ta.dates order by tb.dates desc limit 1) attribute
from ta;

+------------+------+-----------+
| dates      | id   | attribute |
+------------+------+-----------+
| 2017-01-01 |  123 | AD        |
| 2017-01-02 |  123 | AD        |
| 2017-01-03 |  123 | AF        |
| 2017-01-04 |  123 | AA        |
| 2017-01-06 |  123 | AA        |
| 2017-01-07 |  123 | AF        |
| 2017-01-01 |  124 | BE        |
| 2017-01-02 |  124 | BF        |
| 2017-01-03 |  124 | BF        |
| 2017-01-04 |  124 | BA        |
| 2017-01-06 |  124 | AA        |
| 2017-01-07 |  124 | AC        |
+------------+------+-----------+
12 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Please remove the drop/create table commands from the answer, they add nothing and obfuscate the actual answer.

Comment: @P.Salmon thank you for taking the time to answer to this question. I will have to test this because my real tables have thousands of rows/registries. However your answer seems so simple to the problem at hand... perhaps I was making a big deal out of this problem. Cheers! :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I disagree.

Comment: Aparently this solution works out for my problem, and performance is not much compromissed. Thank you, once more, for tanking the time to help me out.